# C++ Function Parameter in a Function

Tags: c++, operating-system

i'm creating a basic OS and i have to make code to print a function because i can't use iostream. 
here's the code from the main kernel which is having the problem:

```
printf(t.__GETTIME__());
```

the printf part is coming up with an error in Visual Studio Code which says

no instance of overloaded function "printf" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (void)

here is my header file which creates the printf function:

```
void printf(char *str)
{
    int STRLEN;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
         VideoMemory[i] = (VideoMemory[i] & 0xFF00) | str[i];
         STRLEN = i;
    }
}
void printf(int *a)
{
    int STRLEN;
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
         VideoMemory[i] = (VideoMemory[i] & 0xFF00) | a[i];
         STRLEN = i;
    }
}
void printf(void(*b)(char));
```

the last `void printf();`
is the problem because i do not know how to link a function in a parameter
ive tried multiple different things and all of the did not work like
`printf( void )` and `printf( void *ptr )`
i may have used the c++ pointer wrong but i haven't seen anything online about this

lastly, if needed, i will put the `t.__GETTIME__();`
.h file here:

```
//there are two underscores in the actual code around TIME and GETTIME
char *time = _TIME_;
template<class T>
class Time { public: void __GETTIME__(); };

template<class T>
void Time<T>::__GETTIME__() { a = __TIME__; }
Time<char> t;
```

hopefully this is enough information to help me if you have any questions please ask

Comment: You declare `__GETTIME__` to be a function returning `void`, meaning it returns nothing. You cannot use a `void` expression as an argument to a function, nor is `void` a valid type for a function parameter. (Declaring a function’s parameters as `(void)` is a special case meaning the function takes no parameters.) Since `__GETTIME__` returns nothing, what do you expect `printf` to print?

Comment: oh, i'm sorry i wasn't thinking that the function gives the variable, i was thinking it just finds the function and runs it through a different kind of way from the header file, thank you for helping me Eric

Comment: The statement `printf(t.__GETTIME__())` is **calling** `__GETTIME__` and passing its return value to `printf()`. To pass `__GETTIME__` itself, you need to drop the function call parenthesis: `printf(t.__GETTIME__)`. However, the 3rd `printf()` overload takes a `void(*b)(char)` as a parameter - a pointer named `b` that points to a function taking a `char` as input and returning `void`. `__GETTIME__` is a member of the `Time` class.  You can't pass a class member to a function pointer, and even if you could, `__GETTIME__` does not take a `char` as input.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ive got it now, ive added a return statement to return `__TIME__` which variable a is equal too and i removed the 3rd printf, i have figured it out now thank you for ur help